# There is any character I need to escape in the value of environment variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

Basically we are thinking about using environment variable to save things like paths, usernames, passwords. Because its a easy way to separate test and production environment and fit well with our RPAs.

So I need to know, there is any character we need to escape to work properly in value when using the command below?

```
SETX PASSWORD_EXEMPLE "VALUE%2TE*STE~/" /M
```

Or any special character.

Comment: This looks like something that would be easy enough to test yourself.

Comment: Your question title and code reflect two completely different things. Almost all normal characters can be used within the string content of a variable, _(you will generally not have any issues with those in paths, usernames and passwords)_. However your question is not about that, it is about passing a string as an argument to `%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe` within a cmd.exe session/batch file. In order to do that, you would need to escape all characters which are considered poisonous to the cmd.exe parser.

Comment: The escape character is generally the caret, `^`, for those poisonous characters, and only in a batch file, as opposed to directly in cmd.exe, the `%` character is used to escape a literal `%` character. The method used to do that may however differ according to your exact code structure, so we cannot assist you with problems occurring when assigning a string from you just submitting one line, especially when that line does not include any poison characters. Please revisit your question using the [edit] facility and provide a more realistic example of a genuine batch file, or cmd.exe sequence.

Comment: Sorry for not been so clear. I just want to know if there is any character I need to worry for the future and be prepared to escape then.
And about not been a good idea, it will run in a VM with restrict access and only the RPAs will use it, so I don't know, even in this case is better using a file like you said?

Comment: In your **edit**, and as an extension of my previous comment, you would need to escape the `%` character if that command was being run from a batch file, otherwise, I cannot see any obvious reason you'd have an issue with that command line, other than you should use `%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe` instead of just the lazy `SETX` string, which relies on variables you have no guarantee of knowing the expanded values of in advance of that command line. If you used what you have there in a batch file, and that line ran when two arguments were in play, `%2` would be expanded to that argument!

Comment: Alright, if I get it, the problem is more in persisting this data by a batch file, with multiple lines, then the data it self. Basically, I already tested, if I persist this env variable value: "Patrick%2Teste^123&~" by Windows GUI, there is no problem, when I take this by... python os.getenv() it returns the right String.
So I can take care about some special character, but anyway I can check the values after running the batch and fix any value that is not correct.

Comment: My fear was more about not been able to fix if any problem occur. (I probably had a bug, I tried to set a value with '%2' even by GUI and was not working, and now is ok like I said)